# Azure WebApp custom PHP server

Tags: php, azure, reactphp, amphp

Is in Azure WebApp any possibility to run custom web server instead of IIS? (amphp/aerys or reactphp/http)

I think, that with Node.js it is possible, so there should be some way for PHP.

Expected behavior is, that I will use my custom PHP server, which will be listening on some port, and IIS only redirect all requests to this port.

But I don't known, if is possible in Azure WebApp run long running app, which will be listening on some port. And this app must start automaticaly.

I can use VM, but web app looks better.

Comment: From the Azure docs: [Create, configure, and deploy a PHP web app to Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-php-get-started/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not, what I want. In this article is described standard approach, where PHP running as CGI inside IIS. But I want build custom server, which will be listening on some port. And IIS will redirect all request to this application. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not custom PHP server on Azure Web Apps, and you cannot attempt to listening to any other ports besides 80 and 443 on Azure Web Apps. You can use VM or Cloud Service instead to approach your requirement.